# What is a Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rakefile

I have started learning Ruby and just tried out my first hello world program in NetBeans IDE. I have one doubt, I can see that the new project wizard created set of package structure. It had one "Rakefile" in it. What does that mean and what is the use of it?

Comment: As a follow-up, you may find these resources helpful: - [Using the Rake Build Language](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html) - [rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake) (there are good links here to additional tutorials or webcasts) - [Basic Rake (video of a talk by Jim Weirich)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFPWDzHWjEY) - [Power Rake (video of a talk by Jim Weirich)](https://vimeo.com/45132438) Jim was the creator and maintainer of Rake before his death in 2014.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It is an alternative to `Makefile` with Ruby syntax.

Comment: What is a Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a rake file to manually kick off a call in the code to import various config files.

My rake file "import_contracts.rake" has the following code:

```
require 'yaml'

task :import_choice_contracts => :environment do
  desc 'Import Choice Contracts for Contract Service'
  path = "/Users/ernst.r/Desktop/import_contract.yml"
  PhiDao::Contract::Service.import_contract_from_file(path)
end
```

This rake task calls the "import_contract_from_file()" method and passes it the path to a file to import. Once the server is running I use the command "rake import_choice_contracts". Its great for testing my code while I still don't have a GUI frontend to call the completed code in the backend.

Fissh