# Trouble building OSRM : What does it mean "re-bootstrap the makefile"?

Tags: linux, makefile, osrm

I am building **OSRM** using the [official tutorial](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-OSRM). Then I encountered a problem and I found [this page](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/901), which is exactly what I need. At the end he said "**re-bootstrap the Makefile**". Could anyone tell me what does it mean and what should I do with makefile exactly?

Comment: Why not ask them? That being said I think they meant that they just needed to regenerate the makefile fresh (as opposed to using the already created/cached version) but I certainly don't know for sure. Additionally, why are you asking?

Comment: I don't know, but I saw in the directory they have a Rakefile. could that be it? Maybe check here for more info on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881482/what-is-a-rakefile . Did you download this project and try building yourself? If not then I wouldn't expect to follow the discussion. Also you should mention in your question what project youre talking about. You linked part of your text to the page, but why not say you have a question about Project OSRM so everyone can find and read what this is about

Comment: I've asked them. I saw the question had been closed so I didn't know if they would see it.

Comment: I still don't know the answer, but maybe reformulate your question like "Trouble building OSRM" and saying what the problem was. Showing your research effort is good but maybe people are passing up your question because you didn't mention build problems in the titel?

Comment: The developer has answered: "re-bootstrap the makefile" means "remove the builddirectory and recreate it. Then reissue the cmake call from it." Thanks for your advice